Reticulate and conda environment
I am trying to enable Python in RStudio using the following link: reticulate
I already had Anaconda installed with Python, so I skipped Python installation step.
Now when I try to select default version of Python (through Global Option), it does not save. I am selecting path to my Anaconda virtual environment. RStudio confirms and restarts, but then produces the following error after print('Hello') command.
reticulate::repl_python()
Error: C:/Users/some_user/AppData/Local/anaconda3/python311.dll - The specified module could not be found.

I am not sure why RStudio is using this path, although the file it is looking for is present.
